# PHP if status and !isset or !isset

Tags: php

I'm trying to match a condition where if the user status is 10 and *ANY* POST variables are not set it triggers an error:

```
if ($_SESSION['status']=='10' && !isset($_POST['a']) || !isset($_POST['B'])) {}
```

I can not use && conditions for any `!isset` as one variable may be set though another might not. I only want the condition to match if one or more variables are not set AND the status==10.

When testing if a `$_POST` variable `!isset`, I remove an `input` element from the page via a browser web tool (e.g. Firebug). When the form is submitted with the variable missing it's *still* passing validation incorrectly.

I am also seeking a PHP if grouping condition.

Comment: grouping condition? you mean like `(brackets)` ??

Comment: yeah good old parenthesis...()

Comment: you can group these: `&& (!isset($_POST['a']) || !isset($_POST['B']))`

Comment: I've tried: `if ($status=='10' && (!isset($_POST['a']) || !isset($_POST['b'])` without success.

Comment: (Aside: Stack Overflow questions are probably better without any references to the voting system or how answers will be graded. This is mainly because it is not germane to the technical content. Also, most readers do not sign in or vote, so this aspect of the site is not interesting to them. You may find also that if you set out a question grading system, an answer is provided that causes you to rethink that grading system. So, in short, this "meta" stuff is best avoided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for *absolutely any* PHP variables, I'd recommend this:

```
if (($_SESSION['status'] == 10) && (count($_POST) > 0)) {
```

You can then get the list of _POST var keys using `array_keys($_POST)`.

If you are looking for a specific:

```
if (($_SESSION['status'] == 10) && (isset($_POST['A']) || isset($_POST['b']))) {
```

The order of the brackets is important. You can separate groups of logical statements with brackets.

Comment: Any PHP $_POST variables is not what I'm trying to do; I need to specifically look for all of the variables and ensure each one isset individually.

Comment: Then pick the second solution and note the order of brackets :-)

Comment: The second part is what I needed and works. The difference was I wasn't using parenthesis for *both* sets.

Answer (score 0):

Is that was what you were looking for?

```
$status = $_SESSION['status'];

if($status == '10'){
    if(!isset($_POST['a']) or !isset($_POST['B'])){
     //Triggers error.
    }else{
     //Another
    }
}
```

Comment: No, single combined if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it a function:

```
function checkAllVars($dataVars, $requestVars) {
    foreach($dataVars as $varname) {
        if(!isset($requestVars[$varname])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$dataVars = array (
"varName1",
"varName2",
"varName3",
"varName4",
);

$allVarsSet = checkAllVars($dataVars, $_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score -1):

you might be looking for

```
if($_SESSION['status']=='10' && (!isset($_POST['a']) || !isset($_POST['B']))){}
                                ^                                          ^
```

which means if status = 10 and (if not set 'a' or not set 'B' or they can be both not set) do something

or you might be looking for

```
if(($_SESSION['status']=='10' && !isset($_POST['a'])) || ($_SESSION['status']=='10' && !isset($_POST['B']))){}
```